# Creating a Makefile in Raspbian

Tags: c, makefile, raspbian

I'm trying to create a Makefile for my C program in Raspbian (Raspberry Pi).
My program consists of a bunch of .c and .h Files. I've looked at countless Makefiles, but I just don't unterstand how it works with multiple files. There are always .o files in the Makefile but as I understand object files are the result of compiling, so I dont have any o. Files as I am trying to compile my .c Files.

Please explain to me how this works.

Edit:

Thank you. So I tried this and it starts compiling but there are errors 'multiple definition'. Example:

These are my Files:

```
main.c main.h
calibration.c calibration.h
file.c file.h
frame.c frame.h
gamepad.c gamepad.h
gpio.c gpio.h
uart.c uart.h
types.h
```

this is my makefile:

```
all: main

main: main.o calibration.o file.o frame.o gamepad.o gpio.o uart.o

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c -std=c99 -Wall $< -o $@ -lncurses
```

Where can i put 'types.h'?
With every file I get errors 'multiple definitions'

Comment: You compile your source (`.c`) files *to* object (`.o`) files. For `gcc` add the `-c` option. Then when you have your object files, you link them together. If you set up your dependencies correct, only the source files you change will be recompiled to object files when you invoke `make`.

Comment: So I compile the .c Files one at a time and then create a makefile where I link all the object files together?

Comment: @user3030653 : No the make file can do of that.  If your real problem is compiling and linking multiple sources, rather than a specific need for makefiles, then an IDE such as Code::Blocks will do that for you, and is available on RPi via aptget, and has other advantages such as a GUI interface to GDB and code syntax highlighting and navigation.

Answer (score 2):

The basic syntax of a `make` rule is:

```
target … : prerequisites …
    recipe
    …
    …
```

On the left of the semicolon are the targets. The targets are your object files(`.o`). On the right of the semicolon are the files that you will need to create this file. Those files are the source files(`.c`).

Lets give a basic example of what such a rule could look like.

```
%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

The `%` sign is a wildcard. `%.o` means everything that ends with `.o`. So, if you want to make an object file, you can say `make file.o`, and `make` will try to find a rule with which it can make this target. This happens to be the rule I just showed as an example, because `file.o` matches `%.o`.

Then the `recipe`. This is what will be executed. Usually it's about invoking the compiler(`gcc`), and feeding it the source file to generate the object file. That's what we do with `gcc -c $< -o $@`. The `$<` and `$@` mean `target` and `prerequisites` respectively.

So, what happens when you 'just' want to build your program? You usually will type `make`, and it will build. The default rule that's used when you type `make`, is `all`. So, if you make a rule about `all`,  then you can specify what files you want to create to build your program. Example of such a rule:

```
all: main
```

Then, when `make` is invoked, it will find that rule and finds out it needs `main`. To create `main` you need another rule:

```
main: file.o
```

This rule says that to build `main`, you need `file.o`. So, when you put all of the example rules together you get this:

```
all: main

main: file.o

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

Note that you can specify more than one file, so instead of `file.o`, you can say `file.o main.o other_file.o` etc. Every prerequisite that you specify will be made, if they can find a rule to make it.

Comment: I understand. But how does this work with multiple source files? Can I have one target with the name of my program and put all my source files in the prerequisites?

Comment: See my edit. If you have any more questions, I'd be glad to answer them.

Comment: Thank you. So I tried this and it starts compiling but there are errors 'multiple definition'. Example:

These are my Files:
main.c main.h
calibration.c calibration.h
file.c file.h
frame.c frame.h
gamepad.c gamepad.h
gpio.c gpio.h
uart.c uart.h
types.h

this is my makefile:

all: main

main: main.o calibration.o file.o frame.o gamepad.o gpio.o uart.o

%.o: %.c
 gcc -c -std=c99 -Wall $< -o $@ -lncurses

Where can i put 'types.h'?
With every file I get errors 'multiple definitions'

Comment: That error has not much to do with the makefile. The header files are being included by source files. If you pass a source file to the compiler, the compiler will use a so called 'preprocessor', use Google to find out more about this. You are probably including the same header files multiple times, which means multiple definitions will occur. Use 'header guards' for that.

Comment: Then find out why there are multiple definitions in your source files. This can be different in each case. Perhaps you include the same header file twice, etc.

Comment: Please take another look at my first post, I've added filenames and my makefile. Please tell me if I did this correctly, especially the -lncurses flag and what can I do with headerfiles (types.h)? Do I have to add a source file 'types.c'?

Comment: I think you might create another question for this problem. This problem of yours is beyond the scope of the original question. Please take a good look at how the compiler works, and especially the preprocessor.

Answer (score 2):

A very simple but typical makefile could look like this

```
SOURCES = source1.c source2.c source3.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

TARGET = myExecutable

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    gcc $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
    gcc -c $< -o $@
```

The complicated parts:

- `SOURCES = source1.c source2.c source3.c` This is a variable definition, it assigns the string `"source1.c source2.c source3.c` to the variable `SOURCES`.
- `$(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)` This is a shorthand for the `patsubst` [text function](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Text-Functions). It takes all text from the `$(SOUCES)` variable, and replaces the pattern `%.c` with `%.o`, i.e. it takes e.g. the string `source1.c` and replace it with `source1.o`.
- `$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)` This makes `myExecutable` depend on all object files, meaning if one object file is modified then the command in the rule will be executed.
- `gcc $^ -o $@` This calls the `gcc` command, passing all dependencies (`$^`) as arguments (that is, all object files), and tells `gcc` to output a file with the name of the target (`$@`).
- `%.o: %.c` This is the rule that makes object files depend in their source file. So if you have `source1.c` then `source1.o` will depend on that source file.
- `gcc -c $< -o $@` This is the command that compiles the source file (the first dependency, `$<`) to an object file (with the `-c` option) and name it as the target of the rule (`$@`).

Also note that if you invoke `make` without a specific target, then the first rule will be selected. In the case of the above makefile, it will be the `$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)` rule which will make sure that all object files are build from the source files, and then link the object files into the resulting executable.