# make file compilation error "fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory"

Tags: c, makefile, raspbian, raspberry-pi2

I am trying to compile a c module by Makefile I created but I am getting error **fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory**. Below are codes of c program and Makefile. Exactly the errors is:

```
sudo make
gcc -I/home/pi/linux-03f35fe498e5516091e4fd66d1700e8d0b0f4915/include -c my_loader.c -o my_loader.o
In file included from /home/pi/linux-03f35fe498e5516091e4fd66d1700e8d0b0f4915/include/linux/kernel.h:6:0,
                 from /home/pi/linux-03f35fe498e5516091e4fd66d1700e8d0b0f4915/include/linux/list.h:8,
                 from /home/pi/linux-03f35fe498e5516091e4fd66d1700e8d0b0f4915/include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from my_loader.c:1:
/home/pi/linux-03f35fe498e5516091e4fd66d1700e8d0b0f4915/include/linux/linkage.h:7:25: fatal error: asm/linkage.h: No such file or directory
 #include <asm/linkage.h>
                         ^
compilation terminated.
Makefile:10: recipe for target 'my_loader.o' failed
make: *** [my_loader.o] Error 1
```

**C Module**

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/kmod.h>
#include <linux/platform_device.h>
#include <sound/simple_card.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

void device_release_callback(struct device *dev) { /* do nothing */ };

static struct asoc_simple_card_info snd_rpi_simple_card_info = {
.card = "snd_rpi_simple_card", // -> snd_soc_card.name
.name = "simple-card_codec_link", // -> snd_soc_dai_link.name
.codec = "snd-soc-dummy", // "dmic-codec", // -> snd_soc_dai_link.codec_name
.platform = "20203000.i2s",
.daifmt = SND_SOC_DAIFMT_I2S | SND_SOC_DAIFMT_NB_NF | SND_SOC_DAIFMT_CBM_CFM,
.cpu_dai = {
.name = "20203000.i2s", // -> snd_soc_dai_link.cpu_dai_name
.sysclk = 0 },
.codec_dai = {
.name = "snd-soc-dummy-dai", //"dmic-codec", // -> snd_soc_dai_link.codec_dai_n$
.sysclk = 0 },
};
static struct platform_device snd_rpi_simple_card_device = {
.name = "asoc-simple-card", //module alias
.id = 0,
.num_resources = 0,
.dev = { .release = &device_release_callback,
.platform_data = &snd_rpi_simple_card_info, // *HACK ALERT*
},
};


int hello_init(void)
{
const char *dmaengine = "bcm2708-dmaengine"; //module name
int ret;

ret = request_module(dmaengine);
pr_alert("request module load '%s': %d\n",dmaengine, ret);
ret = platform_device_register(&snd_rpi_simple_card_device);
pr_alert("register platform device '%s': %d\n",snd_rpi_simple_card_device.name,$

pr_alert("Hello World :)\n");
return 0;
}
void hello_exit(void)
{// you'll have to sudo modprobe -r the card & codec drivers manually (first?)
platform_device_unregister(&snd_rpi_simple_card_device);
pr_alert("Goodbye World!\n");
}
module_init(hello_init);
module_exit(hello_exit);
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("ASoC simple-card I2S setup");
MODULE_AUTHOR("Plugh Plover");
```

**Makefile**

```
SOURCES = my_loader.c
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:%.c=%.o)

TARGET = myExecutable

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
        gcc $^ -o $@

%.o: %.c
        gcc -I/home/pi/linux-03f35fe498e5516091e4fd66d1700e8d0b0f4915/include -$< -o $@
```

I am on Raspbian Jessie and `uname -r` returns *4.4.38-v7+*. There are many similar questions here on Stackoverflow but non of them worked for me.

Comment: `sudo make`, why `sudo` Oo?

Comment: I got same error without `sudo`.

Comment: Doesn't `gcc $^ -o $@` attempt to create an executable when you have told it to compile to obj `-c`? (that may be fine, it just caught my eye)

Comment: I don't know how exactly it works. I followed an example to create make file. Please suggest me if you want to change something?

Comment: Here is the example I followed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27418767/creating-a-makefile-in-raspbian

Comment: The kernel headers (I don't know where did you fetch them) are a tree of directories, and it seems that one of them is "asm/", which you are missing. Try to download the kernel headers using the package manager, if you can - it does a good work.

Comment: I downloaded the kernal source using [rpi-source](https://github.com/notro/rpi-source/wiki) package.

Comment: Is there no solution for my problem!?
@linuxfan I did! Still no luck...

Comment: @user7276343 You could try two things. 1) Build the whole kernel - maybe  the process creates some needed files. 2) Go the hard way: search for linkage.h and put it in asm/, i.e., exactly where it is expected to be (but note, it seems there are two files named linkage.h, and one refers to the other - kind of weird).

Comment: BTW - don't get in the habit of recklessly trying `sudo` when something doesn't work without it :-)